# How to detect hitting a layer with a ray using Physics2d.raycast

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a building aspect to the game which I am making in unity using c#. I need to detect whether I am building on a certain layer.

I have tried to edit the code down below multiple times but I can't seem to find the problem. I have also watched multiple videos which explain that my code should work but maybe I'm just not seeing something. Any help would be great.

This is the code that I have for the layer detection:

```
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask weaponNoBuildLayer;
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask pathNoBuildLayer;

private bool buildBlocked = false;

private GameObject blockTemplate;

        blockTemplate.transform.position = new Vector2(newPosx, newPosy);

        RaycastHit2D rayHit;
        if(currentBlock.isWeapon == true)
        {
            rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(blockTemplate.transform.position, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, weaponNoBuildLayer);
        }
        else
        {
            rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast(blockTemplate.transform.position, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, pathNoBuildLayer);
        }
        if(rayHit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("yh");
            buildBlocked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            buildBlocked = false;
        }
```

What this should do is set the Boolean buildBlocked to true if the ray collides with certain layers (set as layermasks further up in the code) yet it doesn't and buildBlocked is permanently false. Again, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

```
// Bit shift the index of the layer (8) to get a bit mask
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        // This would cast rays only against colliders in layer 8.
        // But instead we want to collide against everything except layer 8. The ~ operator does this, it inverts a bitmask.
        layerMask = ~layerMask;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
        }
```